# Output of numbers are incorrect sometimes.

Tags: java

This is my task, Given an input of an expression consisting of a string of letters and operators (plus sign, minus sign, and letters. IE: ‘b-d+e-f’) and a file with a set of variable/value pairs separated by commas (i.e: a=1,b=7,c=3,d=14) write a program that would output the result of the inputted expression.
For example, if the expression input was ("a + b+c -d") and the file input was ( a=1,b=7,c=3,d=14) the output would be -3. 
Hi I am trying to do a simple java code which outputs a number if i add 4 letters. When I do different combinations like d-c+a+b it gives me a inccorect number like 118.0. Can someone tell me where in my code my calculations are wrong..

Thank you

the ValVarPairs.txt contains these numbers-> a=100,b=5,c=10,d=13

This is what i coded.

```
    package com.ecsgrid;

import java.io.*;

public class testC {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int i = 0,j = 0;
  double result, values[] = new double[4];
  char k, operators[] = new char[3];
  for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) 
    operators[i] = '+';      // default is to add the values

  File myfile;
  StreamTokenizer tok;
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String InputText;

  i = 0;
  try {
    myfile = new File("C:\\VarValPairs.txt");
    tok = new StreamTokenizer(new FileReader(myfile));  
    tok.eolIsSignificant(false);

    while ((tok.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) && (i <= 3)){
      if ((tok.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER))
        values[i++] = tok.nval;
      }
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException e) { System.err.println(e);  return; }
  catch(IOException f) { System.out.println(f); return; }

  System.out.println("Enter letters and operators:");

  try {
    InputText = in.readLine(); 
  }  
  catch(IOException f) { System.out.println(f); return; }

  for (i = 0; i < InputText.length(); i++)
  {
     k = InputText.charAt(i);
     if ((k == '+') || (k == '-'))
     {
        if (j <= 2) operators[j++] = k;   
     }
  } 

  result = values[0];
  for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
   if (operators[i] == '+')
     result = result + values[i+1];  
   else
     result = result - values[i+1];
  }
  System.out.println(result);  
 }
}
```

Comment: this isnt a class assignment, im trying to teach myself java. thank you very much. if you can help, then help please keep your smart remarks to yourself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572320/output-incorrect/19572400#19572400 answered it in the duplicate question that you made. `@[A mod or someone who knows] Should I be deleting my answer there and reposting it here?`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your calculations are wrong, but you could do something like this:

EDITED CODE:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class test{
        public static int a;
        public static int b;
        public static int c;
        public static int d;
        public static int fin = 0;
        public static String temp;
        public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("yourfile.txt"));
            temp = "";
            while(input.hasNext()){ //stores the letters
                temp = temp + input.next();   
            }
            input.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
            /*
            THIS IS IF THE FILE yourfile.txt IS IN THIS FORMAT EXACTLY:
            a=1
            b=2
            c=3
            d=4
            */
            for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){ //intitializes the values
                String message = "" + temp.charAt(i);
                if(message.equals("a") || message.equals("b") || message.equals("c") || message.equals("d")){
                    String val = "" + temp.charAt(i+2);
                    setValue(message,val);
                }
            }
            Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("ENTER EXPRESSION: ");
            String ex = enter.nextLine();
            for(int b = 0; b < ex.length(); b++){
                String m = ""+ ex.charAt(b);
                if(b == 0){
                    if(m.equals("a") || m.equals("b") || m.equals("c") || m.equals("d")){
                        fin = fin + getValue(m);   
                    }
                }
                else{
                if(m.equals("a") || m.equals("b") || m.equals("c") || m.equals("d")){
                   String check = "" + ex.charAt(b-1);
                   if(check.equals("+")){
                        fin = fin + getValue(m);  
                    }
                    if(check.equals("-")){
                        fin = fin - getValue(m); 
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(fin);
        }
        public static void setValue(String variable, String value){
            if(variable.equals("a")){
                a = Integer.parseInt(value);   
            }
            if(variable.equals("b")){
                b = Integer.parseInt(value);   
            }
            if(variable.equals("c")){
                c = Integer.parseInt(value);   
            }
            if(variable.equals("d")){
                d = Integer.parseInt(value);   
            }
        }
        public static int ret = 0;
        public static int getValue(String var){
           if(var.equals("a")){
                ret = a; 
            }
            if(var.equals("b")){
                ret = b;
            }
            if(var.equals("c")){
                ret = c;  
            }
            if(var.equals("d")){
                ret = d;   
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

There are some problems in your code where you use `"=="` instead of `.equals()`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Sting cannot be resolved to a type

 at com.ecsgrid.testC.main(testC.java:34)
when i write your code, thats the error i get