# Output incorrect

Tags: java, parsing

When I do different combinations like d-c+a+b it gives me a inccorect number like 118.0. Can someone tell me where in my code my calculations are wrong..
Thank you

the ValVarPairs.txt contains these numbers-> a=100,b=5,c=10,d=13
This is what i coded.

```
package com.ecsgrid;

import java.io.*;

public class testC {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int i = 0,j = 0;
  double result, values[] = new double[4];
  char k, operators[] = new char[3];
  for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) 
    operators[i] = '+';      // default is to add the values

  File myfile;
  StreamTokenizer tok;
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String InputText;

  i = 0;
  try {
    myfile = new File("C:\\VarValPairs.txt");
    tok = new StreamTokenizer(new FileReader(myfile));  
    tok.eolIsSignificant(false);

    while ((tok.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) && (i <= 3)){
      if ((tok.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER))
        values[i++] = tok.nval;
      }
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException e) { System.err.println(e);  return; }
  catch(IOException f) { System.out.println(f); return; }

  System.out.println("Enter letters and operators:");

  try {
    InputText = in.readLine(); 
  }  
  catch(IOException f) { System.out.println(f); return; }

  for (i = 0; i < InputText.length(); i++)
  {
     k = InputText.charAt(i);
     if ((k == '+') || (k == '-'))
     {
        if (j <= 2) operators[j++] = k;   
     }
  } 

  result = values[0];
  for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
   if (operators[i] == '+')
     result = result + values[i+1];  
   else
     result = result - values[i+1];
  }
  System.out.println(result);  
 }
}
```

Comment: learn to use a debugger

Comment: Do not post duplicates like this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's debug this a little, add a few system outs...

this is what you would see for each step
100.0 - 5.0
95.0 +  10.0
105.0 + 13.0
118.0

your value array is {100,5,10,13} and your operator array is {-,+,+}

you have not mapped a = 100, b = 5, c= 10, d = 13, unless you map those then parse the operands using the mapping based on the non operand input keys, it is not going to work.

So, if I were to use the character's int values, I would be able to translate it this way.

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        double result, values[] = new double[4];
        char k, operatorsAndOperands[] = new char[3];
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            operatorsAndOperands[i] = '+'; // default is to add the values

        File myfile;
        StreamTokenizer tok;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String InputText;

        i = 0;
        try {
            myfile = new File("C:\\VarValPairs.txt");
            tok = new StreamTokenizer(new FileReader(myfile));
            tok.eolIsSignificant(false);

            while ((tok.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) && (i <= 3)) {
                if ((tok.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER))
                    values[i++] = tok.nval;
            }
            for (int l = 0; l < values.length; l++) {
                System.out.println(values[l]);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        } catch (IOException f) {
            System.out.println(f);
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter letters and operators:");

        try {
            InputText = in.readLine().toUpperCase();
        } catch (IOException f) {
            System.out.println(f);
            return;
        }

        if(InputText.length() > 0){
            operatorsAndOperands = new char[InputText.length()];
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Operations specified");
            return;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < InputText.length(); i++) {
            k = InputText.charAt(i);
            operatorsAndOperands[j++] = k;
        }

        result = 0; 
        for (i = 0; i < operatorsAndOperands.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(operatorsAndOperands[i] + " " + (int)operatorsAndOperands[i]);
            if(i+1<operatorsAndOperands.length)
                System.out.println(operatorsAndOperands[i+1]);
            switch(operatorsAndOperands[i]){
            case '+':
                if(operatorsAndOperands[i+1] != '+' && operatorsAndOperands[i+1] != '-'){
                    result+=values[(int)operatorsAndOperands[i+1] - (int)'A'];
                    i++;
                }
                break;
            case '-':
                if(operatorsAndOperands[i+1] != '+' && operatorsAndOperands[i+1] != '-'){
                    result-=values[(int)operatorsAndOperands[i+1] - (int)'A'];
                    i++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                result = values[(int)operatorsAndOperands[i] - (int)'A'];
                break;
            };
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: One way would be to use a Hashmap to map a to 100 b to 5 etc., or use the int values of the chars to get the operator values, see my edit.

Comment: THANK you so much myth, I have resolved it with your help..

Answer (score 2):

**Right now you would be getting the same output if your input was `-++`**

You never parse for the order or a, b, c and d. You always assume the order a->b->c->d.

So d-c+a+b will be: a-b+c+d which is consistent with the output you provided(100-5+10+13 = 118)

> OP's CODE
>
> > ```
> >   for (i = 0; i < InputText.length(); i++)
> >   {
> >      k = InputText.charAt(i);
> >      if ((k == '+') || (k == '-'))
> >      {
> >         if (j <= 2) operators[j++] = k;   
> >      }
> >   }
> > ```
> >
> > /OP'S CODE

In this loop, when k is not an operator, you should be reading which letter it is, and store the order in which the letters appeared. Or build some other kind of mapping. In any case you can't just ignore non-operator characters because they are part of the input.

Comment: how do i choose which one is the operator if K isn't

Comment: @soupi7 k will at some point be every character. You're right now looping through the whole string, finding the operators, and putting them into an array. While you're doing that. If k isn't an operator(an else on that if statement) then you'll need to implement some kind of logic that will save which character it is. on the first iteration, k will be d. Put 'd' into an array, do you know that it came first.

Comment: I put d in the arrray and same issue still

Comment: can you rewrite it so it shows me that k will be d and d into the array?

Comment: @soupi7 no problem. Sorry, I didn't have time to write you a full solution, but I'm glad you were able to figure out.